# SwiftEntryKit returns error when present Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1e0)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, exc-bad-access

```
     public func displayCustomAttributes() {
        // Create a basic toast that appears at the top
        var attributes = EKAttributes.topToast

        // Set its background to white
        attributes.entryBackground = .color(color: .white)

        // Animate in and out using default translation
        attributes.entranceAnimation = .translation
        attributes.exitAnimation = .translation

        let customView = UIView()
        /*
        ... Customize the view as you like ...
        */

        // Display the view with the configuration
        SwiftEntryKit.display(entry: customView, using: attributes)
    }
```

I tried above basic example to show toast view using [SwiftEntryKit](https://github.com/huri000/SwiftEntryKit) but it returns unrecognize error. Where is the issue?[image]